# Paint scratch or carbon crack?

Tags: frames, carbon, crack

I might just be overly paranoid, but does the line in the image (to the left of the glare) look like a paint scratch or could it be a sign of a spreading crack?[image]

Comment: Looks very much like a scratch because of the way it curves and the white color of the base coat below.

Comment: Definitely just a scratch

Comment: Nothing wrong with being cautious with possible cracks to carbon fibre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert. It looks like a scratch to me because of the curves and the way it doesn't end at a sharp point. However, it's impossible to really tell from a photograph so you should take it in to a bike shop and get them to have a look at it.